# Is it safe to mount /dev into a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I'm affected by an issue described in [moby/moby/27886](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27886), meaning loop devices I create in a Docker container do not appear in the container, but they do on the host.

One of the potential workarounds is to mount /dev into the Docker container, so something like:

```
docker run -v /dev:/dev image:tag
```

I know that it works, at least on Docker Engine and the Linux kernel that I currently use (20.10.5 and 5.4.0-70-generic respectively), but I'm not sure how portable and safe it is.

In runc's [libcontainer/SPEC](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/master/libcontainer/SPEC.md#filesystem) for filesystems I found some detailed information on /dev mounts for containers, so I'm a bit worried that mounting /dev from the host might cause unwanted side-effects. I even found [one problematic use-case](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37645) that was fixed in 2018...

So, is it safe to mount /dev into a Docker container? Is it guaranteed to work?

I'm not asking if it works, because it seems it works, I'm interested if this is a valid usage, natively supported by Docker Engine.

Comment: Define "safe" .

Comment: ....how is this related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase when creating a new issue in moby project on GitHub the recommended approach for seeking general support around Docker is to use StackOverflow with 'docker' tag...

Comment: @KamilCuk safe means it's officially supported by Docker, it's guaranteed to work properly, it's not considered a hack and there are no side-effects. Makes sense?